# $_FILES fail on big files

Tags: php

I have a little uploadscript which is working great for normal sized images and files.

```
    function uploadimage($name,$dir)
{
    if($name['error'] > 0){
    die('An error ocurred when uploading.');
    }

    if(!getimagesize($name['tmp_name'])){
        die('Please ensure you are uploading an image.');
    }

    // Check filetype
    if($name['type'] != 'image/png'){
        die('Unsupported filetype uploaded.');
    }

    // Check filesize
    if($name['size'] > 500000){
        die('File uploaded exceeds maximum upload size.');
    }

    // Check if the file exists
    if(file_exists($dir. $name['name'])){
        die('File with that name already exists.');
    }

    // Upload file
    if(!move_uploaded_file($name['tmp_name'], $dir. $name['name'])){
        die('Error uploading file - check destination is writeable.');
    }

    return $dir. $name['name'];
    die('File uploaded successfully.');
}
```

$name is $_FILES['WHATEVER'] and $dir the dir. Well now I just changed a few lines of it to upload .csv files with it. So far so good. It's working with little .csv files. But when I try a bigger one (20MB+) nothing happens when I post it. I checked my php.ini for upload_max_filesize and memory_limit , both are at 128M ... Someone can give me a pointer where I should search the bug ?

Comment: Webserver configuration. There are lots of existing questions on this topic. Did you read them?

Comment: if($name['size'] > 500000){??

Comment: Is there any error or warning message in the server logs?

Comment: "I just changed a few lines" this line also :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `post_max_size` too.

Comment: No. The upload is not part of the execution time. Execution time is the time spent in the PHP parser.

Answer (score 3):

Two PHP configuration options control the maximum upload size: **upload_max_filesize** and **post_max_size**.

However, you also need to consider the time it takes to complete an upload. PHP scripts normally time-out after 30 seconds, but a 10MB file would take at least 3 minutes to upload on a healthy broadband connection (remember that upload speeds are typically five times slower than download speeds). In addition, manipulating or saving an uploaded image may also cause script time-outs. We therefore need to set PHP’s **max_input_time** and **max_execution_time** to something like 300 (5 minutes specified in seconds).

These options can be set in your server’s **php.ini** configuration file so that they apply to all your applications. Alternatively, if you’re using Apache, you can configure the settings in your application’s .htaccess file:

Comment: In my experience, `max_input_time` is a usual culprit, but the fact is hidden by a confusing error message.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this setting in php.ini file

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M  //20m,30m etc..
post_max_size = 10M  //20m,30m etc..
```

That is not necessary to give 10 MB ,it will give as per your requirements.

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check post_max_size in your php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

you have to change php.ini file. it limits the maximum upload size. change this in php.ini file

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

PHP Uploads [might take the whole request](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php) in memory to work, so uploading multiple hundreds of megs will require memory limit that allows that many megs to be stored (and more). If you really need to support big file uploads, you are probably better off if the webserver does the temporary file creation from the request. Take a look to [mod_upload](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_upload/) for apache, or the [HttpUpload](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadModule) addon for nginx.

Comment: Sorry but that's not how PHP uploads work. The upload is stored in a temporary file and all what PHP handles is the file path (unless *you* explicitly load such file into memory).

Comment: I suppose it could depend on hosting environments, I'm pretty sure this was the case with oldschool apache + mod_cgi setup.

Answer (score -1):

[PHP ini settings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) are what you need to look at.